# Search through SharePoint list - wrong results

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, search-results, enterprise-search, sharepoint-search, sharepoint-list

As always I believe you can help me. :)

I have an issue with **searching through SharePoint list.**

**2 cases:**

*1) I search for an item which number is 251 (this item is included in the searched list).*

The results are: 876, 198, 251, 45.

Why are there so many unconnected items shown in results? Shouldn't be only 251 shown in the results? It's on the 3-rd position only!

*2) I enter in a search box number which doesn't exist on the list: 344*

The results are: 765, 45, 132, 223

Shouldn't be *no search results* there instead of displaying many weird hits?

Any idea why this searching works like this?

Thank you very much in advance!
Aga[image]

Answer (score 0):

The search box at list view web part searches not only for one particular list column whereas it searches if the input value is in any of the indexed columns in that list.

If you want your search to take only Item ID as input and show results based on that then you need to insert another search results web part with custom search query in query builder and attach the search box web part with that search result web part.

Answer (score 0):

As Yayati said, searches not only for one particular list column.

You can construct queries that use property restrictions to narrow the focus of the query to match only results based on a specified condition.

eg: if the managed property of item column is "item", you can search with:

item:344

Property restriction queries in KQL for your reference:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/keyword-query-language-kql-syntax-reference#property-restriction-queries-in-kql